# Симуляция эволюции

Tags: python, tkinter

Я решил написать симуляцию эволюции и естественного отбора на python. И столкнулся с проблемой:как мне сделать так чтобы клетки раздваивались и имели гены? И еще сделать так чтобы они двигались сами без нажатия кнопок мышки

```
 from tkinter import *
 tk=Tk()
 tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
 canvas = Canvas(tk, width=1280, height=1000, highlightthickness=0)



canvas.pack()



tk.update()
class Smart(object):
    def __init__(self,canvas,color):
       self.canvas=canvas
       self.x=0
       self.id=canvas.create_oval(5,5,13,13, fill=color)
       self.canvas.move(self.id, 640, 500)
       def move_oval(event):
           x= event.x
           y = event.y
            canvas.coords(self.id, event.x - 5, event.y - 5, event.x + 5, event.y + 5)
         canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', move_oval)

smart=Smart(canvas, 'blue')
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: *`"как мне сделать так чтобы клетки раздваивались и имели гены?"`*. Насколько я помню биологию,  наверное надо моделировать собственно гены, а также время и окружающую среду, при взаимодействи с которой гены будут воздействовать на клетку и при определенных условиях вызывать ее [митоз](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7)

Comment: спасибоо конечно но мне нужно немного другое. Я пока не могу реализовать всё это сам. Мне нужна помощь с кодом. Может использовать pygame